# Processing C++ comments

Tags: python, parsing

Here's the first functional version of my Python 2 script for processing comments in C++ source files. It's a personal project, I expect to expand it later with more advanced options (mainly about replacing comments with whitespace or marking their original positions in the comment-only output).

It's also intended as a learning excercise. I am self-learned in Python, my primary language is C++. So the core of my question is whether the code is "Pythonic" and if not, how to improve on that. I don't want to "write C++ with a different syntax," I want to (learn to) write proper Python.

I will of course also welcome any other comments (general style, efficiency, safety).

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 

# Copyright Petr Kmoch 2014

"""Script for processing comments and non-comment code in C++ files.

The goal of this script to extract comments from C++ files and output only the comments, only the
non-comment code, or both.

For a quick usage summary, pass '-h' or '--help' as a command-line argument.
"""

import argparse
import os
import re
import sys


class Progress(object):
  """This class stores intermediary data when processing a single line of input.

  It is used as a means of communicating data between the processFile() function and State_*
  objects.

  It contains the following members:
    line: The tail part of the input line which has not been processed yet.
    finished: Boolean flag indicating that the entire line has been processed.
    stateChange:
      If not None, this member holds a callable which takes the state stack as argument
      and will modify it according to the results of processing the line.
    noncomments: String of non-comments extracted from the line during processing.
    comments: String of comments extracted from the line during processing.
  """

  def __init__(self, line):
    object.__init__(self)
    self.line = line
    self.resetProcessing()

  def resetProcessing(self):
    """Clear the results of previously processing a piece of the line.
    """
    self.finished = False
    self.stateChange = None
    self.noncomments = ''
    self.comments = ''

  def extractNoncomment(self, length = None):
    """Move a part of the current line to the `noncomments` member.

    Removes the first `length` characters from `line` and appends them to `noncomments`. If `length`
    is not specified, the entire line is moved.
    """
    self.noncomments += self.extract(length)

  def extractComment(self, length = None):
    """Move a part of the current line to the `comments` member.

    Removes the first `length` characters from `line` and appends them to `noncomments`. If `length`
    is not specified, the entire line is moved.
    """
    self.comments += self.extract(length)

  def extract(self, length):
    """Extract a part of the current line and return it.

    Removes the first `length` characters from `line` and returns them. If `length` is not
    specified, the entire line is used.
    """
    if length is None:
      val = self.line
      self.line = ''
      return val
    else:
      val = self.line[0 : length]
      self.line = self.line[length:]
      return val


class State_Normal(object):
  """State class representing normal C++ code.

  This state represents processing normal C++ code. It is also the initial state in which a file
  starts.
  """

  regex = re.compile('["\'/]')

  def process(self, progress):
    """Process `progress.line` as normal C++ code.

    When this funciton encounters a start of a character literal, string literal or comment, it
    switches state accordingly. Otherwise, it just treats the text it processes as non-comments.
    """
    progress.resetProcessing()
    while progress.line:
      match = self.regex.search(progress.line)
      if not match:
        progress.extractNoncomment()
      elif match.group() == '/':
        nextChar = progress.line[match.start() + 1]
        if nextChar == '/' or nextChar == '*':
          progress.extractNoncomment(match.start())
          progress.extractComment(2)
          if nextChar == '/':
            progress.stateChange = lambda stack: stack.append(State_LineComment())
          else:
            progress.stateChange = lambda stack: stack.append(State_BlockComment())
          return
        else:
          progress.extractNoncomment(match.end())
      else:
        progress.extractNoncomment(match.end())
        progress.stateChange = lambda stack: stack.append(State_Literal(match.group()))
        return
    progress.finished = True


class State_Literal(object):
  """State class representing a character or string literal.

  This state represents processing a character or string literal.
  """

  regexes = {
    '"' : re.compile('["\\\\]')
    , "'" : re.compile("['\\\\]")
  }

  def __init__(self, delim):
    """Initialise for a particular literal type (string or character).

    delim:
      A string containing just the opening delimiter: either a single quote (') or double quote (")
    """
    object.__init__(self)
    self.delim = delim
    self.regex = self.regexes[delim]

  def process(self, progress):
    """Process `progress.line` as the contents of a character or string literal.

    This function processes the line until a non-escaped literal-closing character (' or ") is
    encoutered, at which point it pops this state from the stack. Text processed is treated as a
    non-comment.
    """
    progress.resetProcessing()
    while progress.line:
      match = self.regex.search(progress.line)
      if not match:
        progress.extractNoncomment()
      elif match.group() == '\\':
        progress.extractNoncomment(match.end() + 1) # Extract the backslash and the following character
      else:
        progress.extractNoncomment(match.end())
        progress.stateChange = lambda stack: stack.pop()
        return
    progress.finished = True


class State_LineComment(object):
  """State class representing a //-style comment.

  This state represents processing a comment introduced by //
  """

  regex = re.compile('(\\\\*)\n$')

  def process(self, progress):
    """Process `progress.line` as the contents of a //-style comment.

    The entire line is processed as a comment. Unless it ends with a backslash-escaped newline, this
    state is popped from the stack.
    """
    progress.resetProcessing()
    match = self.regex.search(progress.line)
    if len(match.group(1)) % 2 == 0:
      progress.extractComment()
      progress.noncomments += '\n'
      progress.stateChange = lambda stack: stack.pop()
    else:
      progress.extractComment()
    progress.finished = True


class State_BlockComment(object):
  """State class representing a /* */-style comment.

  This state represents processing a comment delimited by /* and */
  """

  regex = re.compile('\\*/')

  def process(self, progress):
    """Process `progress.line` as the contents of a //-style comment.

    This function processes the line until */ is encountered, at which point it pops this state from
    the stack. Text processed is treated as a comment.
    """
    progress.resetProcessing()
    match = self.regex.search(progress.line)
    if not match:
      progress.extractComment()
      progress.finished = True
    else:
      progress.extractComment(match.end())
      progress.comments += '\n'
      progress.stateChange = lambda stack: stack.pop()


def createArgParser(progName):
  """Create and initialise an argparse.ArgumentParser object.

  This function returns a argument parsing object initialised for parsing ccp arguments.

  progName: String to use as the program's name in the command-line usage help.
  """
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description = 'C and C++ comment processor'
    , prog = progName
  )
  parser.add_argument(
    '-c', '--comments'
    , nargs = '?'
    , type = argparse.FileType('w')
    , const = sys.stdout
    , help = '\
Output comments, optionally specifying a destination file. \
If -c is used and -o is not, non-comment output will be suppressed. \
When COMMENT_FILE is not specified, standard output is used.\
'
    , metavar = 'COMMENT_FILE'
    , dest = 'commentFile'
  )
  parser.add_argument(
    '-o', '--output'
    , nargs = '?'
    , type = argparse.FileType('w')
    , const = sys.stdout
    , help = '\
Output non-comments, optionally specifying a destination file. \
This is the default action if none of -o and -c is specified. \
When OUTPUT_FILE is not specified, standard output is used.\
'
    , metavar = 'OUTPUT_FILE'
    , dest = 'outputFile'
  )
  parser.add_argument(
    'inputFile'
    , nargs = '?'
    , type = argparse.FileType('r')
    , default = sys.stdin
    , help = '\
Input file to process. If not specified, standard input is used.\
'
    , metavar = 'INPUT_FILE'
  )
  return parser


def parseArguments(args):
  """Parse the command line `args` and return the resulting options.

  args:
    Sequence of command-line arguments, including the program being invoked. Typical use is passing
    `sys.argv`.
  """
  parser = createArgParser(os.path.basename(args[0]))
  return parser.parse_args(args[1:])


def validate(options):
  """Validate options retrieved from commandline.

  This function detects invalid settings in `options` (which are assumed to come from parsing
  command-line arguments), if any. It also does general post-processing of the options beyond what
  can be expressed in `argparse`.
  """
  if not options.outputFile and not options.commentFile:
    options.outputFile = sys.stdout


def process(options):
  """Act on valid `options`.

  This function processes the inputs specified in `options`. Each input file is fed to
  processFile().
  """
  processFile(options.inputFile, options)


def processFile(inputFile, options):
  """Process `inputFile` according to `options`.

  This function parses `inputFile`, spits it into the comment and non-comment parts, and outputs
  one or both of them based on the settings in `options`.
  """
  stateStack = [State_Normal()]
  for line in inputFile:
    progress = Progress(line)
    while not progress.finished:
      stateStack[-1].process(progress)
      if progress.stateChange:
        progress.stateChange(stateStack)
      if options.outputFile and progress.noncomments:
        options.outputFile.write(progress.noncomments)
      if options.commentFile and progress.comments:
        options.commentFile.write(progress.comments)


def main(args):
  options = parseArguments(args)
  validate(options)
  process(options)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

One thing I am aware of is that the code does not handle trigraphs; they are somewhere near the end of the to-do list.

Comment: Did you take '\' and `//?` into account? :)

Comment: @Morwenn How are these special? I don't handle trigraphs, though, and I should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: These are special for EOL comments since they can "invalidate" a line break.

Comment: @Morwenn A `//` comment continuation caused by a backslash is accounted for. With `//?`, did you perhaps mean the `??/` trigraph?

Comment: Yes, totally `??/`. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few brief comments from an initial read through:

- A lot of your method names are mixed case, but the Python convention is lowercase with underscores. The Python style guide is [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

  > Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
  >
  > mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility.

  PEP 8 also recommends 4 spaces for indentation, rather than the 2 space which you’ve used, but that’s not worth getting too worked up about.
- Why do the docstrings for `extractNonComment` and `extractComment` both say they append to `noncomments`, when this doesn’t seem to match what they’re actually doing?
- Within the `extract` method: if in an initial bound in a string slice isn’t set, it defaults to 0, so you can replace `val = self.line[0 : length]` by `val=self.line[:length]`.

  Next, string slices that start or end in `None` return the whole string. For example:

  ```
  >>> my_string = "12345\n"
  >>> my_string[:None]
  "12345\n"
  ```

  So you don’t need to check for `length is None` explicitly: just set `val = self.line[:length]`. Then you could just trim `self.line` by the length of `val`. Something like:

  ```
  def extract(self, length = None):
      val = self.line[:length]
      self.line = self.line[len(val):]
      return val
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the review. `lowercase_underscores` will be painful for me, but I guess I'll have to adapt :-( The `noncomments` is just silly C&P. Regarding the `None` indexing: I didn't know that, great tip. But is it known well enough not to induce a "wtf" from someone reading the code? I wouldn't like to sacrifice clarity to tersity with this.

Comment: @Angew when you're using slice notation, you're calling the `__getitem__(self, key)` operator..  Key can either be an int, or a slice containing `key.start`, `key.stop` and `key.step`. If you use slice notation and leave any of them out they get sent as None. `if start is None: start = 0`, `if stop is None: stop = len(self)`, `if step is None: step = 1`